# Titling a Histogram based on the Column Name

Tags: r, histogram

I want to call multiple commands on a column in this data.frame. I.e., I want `summary(X)`, `geoMean(X)`, and `hist(X)` so I can quickly populate a table with the appropriate data for 50+ columns. My function is as follows:

```r
basicstats = function(x){
    a = summary(x); 
    b = geoMean(x, na.rm = TRUE); 
    hist(x, main = x); 
    print(a); 
    print(b)
}
```

When I call `basicstats()` , the summary and the geoMean turn out great. But the histogram title looks like this!

[image]

Obviously my problem is that I need to change `main = x` such that the title is the column name of x, rather than the data of x. I can't get `colnames()` to work on the vector x. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `x`? A vector? If so, you'd need to add another parameter for the name; it's otherwise not being passed in unless you want to use `deparse(substitute(x))`, if you can assume it was passed in as a variable name. If `x` is a data frame or matrix or something, you can pull out the names from the surrounding data structure and pass it to `main`.

Comment: @alistaire brilliant! deparse(substitute(x)) works perfectly for passing in the column name of the vector. thank you for taking the time to help me out. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of @alistaire -- I needed to pass in the name of the vector using `deparse(substitute(x))`. Works perfectly.